# How to keep special characters when doing a redirect on wordpress with either the .htaccess or Simple 301 Redirects Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Ok so im trying to set up a 301 redirect from a wordpress site to another site. The requirement is to link to a category page (There is no category page just a product filter which is why the **To** link is the way it is). The link marked **To** below seems to work perfectly when I copy into browser and click it. For some reason with both the 301 redirect plugin and also with the .htaccess it strips the following characters from the url "**+**", "**%**" as can be seen below. Is there some kinda of function or escape characters that can be used to prevent this issue?

**From** /product-category/vaisala/barometric-pressure/

**To** https://www.vaisala.com/en/search?k=&content_group=products+and+services&measurement%5B%5D=816

The **To** Link keeps defaulting to the following:
https://www.vaisala.com/en/search?k=&content_group=productsandservices&measurement0=816

Has anyone else come across something like this before?

```
Redirect 301 /product-category/vaisala/barometric-pressure/ https://www.vaisala.com/en/search?k=&content_group=products+and+services&measurement%5B%5D=816
```

Comment: Please add what you have in htaccess currently.

Comment: You are sure the `.htaccess` is stripping the characters? `curl -I https://host/product-category/vaisala/barometric-pressure/` gives back 301 with `k=&content_group=productsandservices&measurement0=816`?

Comment: Both the .htaccess and the plugin strip the characters and also what you have posted is incorrect, you have posted the url with the stripped out characters, there should be "+" and "%" in the url as I mentioned in the question

Comment: I actually read that wrong, apologies and yes I'm sure, i tried .htaccess and a plugin